# Best Practice: Can constructor be complex?

Tags: constructor, software-design

I have the following class

```
class Car{
 String modelName;
 Headlight headlight;
 Wiper wiper;

public Car(String modelName){
 this.modelName = modelName;
 this.headlight = HeadlightDao.findByModelName(modelName).getHeadlight();
 this.wiper = WiperDao.findByModelName(modelName).getWiper();
 }
}
```

Is it wrong (read anti-pattern) to have too much construction logic into the constructor?

If i extract the Database connections then the objects will no longer remain immutable.

If i create he Wiper and Headlight beforehand, then i will be exposing the details of what is inside the case to the client?

Comment: I wouldn't make DB calls in a constructor. Is not obvious unless you see the internal code, members of the team can miss this, and bugs may arise.

EDIT: This is a comment and not an answer because I'm just talking about DB calls in constructors, not about complexity in them.

Comment: It's not necessarily wrong to expose that a `Car` has a `Headlight` and a `Wiper`, as long as you don't allow them to be accessed directly.

Comment: From what I see it is a bad example. If you have all kinds of headlights and wipers for different cars, why don't you have cars in database with direct relation one->many? If you have all cars in database, you don't need to fetch headlights/wipers because this would be a responsibility of the ORM, all you need is to fetch a car by model in initializer.

Comment: Also, if you really need to make DB calls to construct a Car (maybe for legacy database design or stuff like that) I would suggest this strategy:


`public static Car ConstructCarFromModelName(String modelName){`
` Car auxCar = new Car();`
` auxCar.modelName = modelName;`
` auxCar.headlight = HeadlightDao.findByModelName(modelName).getHeadlight();`
` auxCar.wiper = WiperDao.findByModelName(modelName).getWiper();`
` return auxCar;`
` }`

Comment: Sorry, had problems with my prev comment:

Also, if you really need to make DB calls to construct a Car (maybe for legacy database design or stuff like that) I would suggest this strategy:

http://pastebin.com/twSRggr9

(With a default private constructor)

Comment: Generally constructor's are used for initializing the variables at the time of creation of object. If something can be done outside a constructor, avoid doing it inside. Later, when you know your class is otherwise well-behaved, you might risk doing it inside.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor should not be complex.

The idea of a constructor is to assist in creating new objects. I will rewrite your code to something like this

```cs
class Headlight{
    string modelName;

    public Headlight(string _modelName){
        this.modelName = _modelName;
    }
}

class Wiper{
    string modelName;

    public Wiper(string _modelName){
        this.modelName = _modelName;
    }
}

class Car{
    string modelName;
    Headlight headlight;
    Wiper wiper;

    public Car(string _modelName)
    {
         this.modelName = _modelName;
         this.headlight = new Headlight(modelName);
         this.wiper = new Wiper(modelName);
    }
}
```

I know this doesn't look like it makes sense but your code looks like it's getting default values from a repository so if it is required to get the default values somewhere else then I think that you can freely use your code. But if you are getting a car details by modelName you should have something like this:

```cs
class Car{
   string modelName;
   Headlight headlight;
   Wiper wiper;

   public Car(){
   }

   public Car(string _modelName, Headlight _headlight, Wiper _wiper){
        this.modelName = _modelName;
        this.headlight = _headlight;
        this.wiper = _wiper;
   }

}

class carService{
   public Car getCarByModel(string modelName){
       //this is just a sample code where you get something from your repository
       var carDAO = repoService.getCarByModel(modelName);
       return new Car(carDAO.modelName, carDAO.headlight, carDAO.wiper);
   }
}
```